# Oracle Apex: how to link an item in a normal page to an item on a modal page

Tags: oracle, modal-dialog, oracle-apex, refresh, textfield

This is my issue: I have a text field item in a normal page (P7_PRODUCT), in this page there is a button that opens a modal page and, in the modal page there is another text field item (P7_PRODUCT). I would like that when I write a product in P7_PRODUCT, the same product appears in P8_PRODUCT. I tried with several dynamic actions, but none of them worked.

Comment: What is the action of the button ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option.

- on page 7, there are: `P7_PRODUCT` text item and `P7_GOTO_8` button
- let button Submit the page
- create **branch**

  - name it e.g. "Goto 8"
  - it should redirect to page 8
  - in "Link Builder", set `P8_PRODUCT` item to `&P7_PRODUCT.` (note leading ampersand and trailing dot)

    [image]
- run page 7
- enter *something* into the `P7_PRODUCT` item
- press the button
- modal dialog page opens and its `P8_PRODUCT` contains value you entered on page 7

  [image]

Comment: That was my first thought too, and while this works, it's not the advised pattern as described here: https://hardlikesoftware.com/weblog/2017/01/05/passing-data-in-and-out-of-apex-dialogs/. There is a nice explanation on how to use one of the techniques described in that blog [here](https://jeffkemponoracle.com/2022/02/)

Comment: Whoa, whole lot of options! Thank you, @Koen.

Comment: I just put together a local example based on that blog by Jeffrey Kemp will post in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

A good blog to read is [this](https://hardlikesoftware.com/weblog/2017/01/05/passing-data-in-and-out-of-apex-dialogs/) one, by John Snyders from the apex development team. As he explains, it's not advised to branch to a modal dialog - instead you should link to it.

Here is an example based on techniques described in [this] (https://jeffkemponoracle.com/2022/02/reusable-region-as-a-modal-page/) blog.

I have 2 pages: Page 108 (normal page) and page 109 (modal page). Page 108 has a region (Region 1) with page item P108_NEW and a button called TO_MODAL. Page 109 has page item P109_NEW. When a user enters a value in P108_NEW and clicks the button, page 109 should open with the value from P108_NEW shown in P109_NEW.

The technique generates the url of the modal page and then redirects to it.

1. Give the region on page 108 a static id: "region1". This is used if you want to create a dynamic action on close of the dialog.
2. Create a new hidden item on page 108 (P108_URL_TO_MODAL1) to hold the value of the modal page url. Source type: Expression, source:

```
apex_page.get_url(
    p_page => 109,
    p_triggering_element => '$(''#region1'')'
)
```

Make sure to set "Used" to "Always, replacing any existing value in session state".

3. Create a dynamic action on click of button on page 108.
4. Add an action to the dynamic action of type pl/sql to set the value on page 109.

Action 1: Execute Server-side Code, Pl/SQL Code:

```
:P109_NEW := :P108_NEW;
```

Values to submit: P108_NEW

Action 2: Execute Javascript code:

```
apex.navigation.redirect("&P108_URL_TO_MODAL1.");
```

This should be it.